# Check if user is older then 18 in Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9

We have the problem that a customer needs to enter his Date of Birth.

The DOB field is selected as required, however, theres no check for the age itself.

How can I modify templates in order to check if the entered age is `>= 18`? Checkout process should throw an error if the customer is not at least 18.

Comment: just chk these extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/age-verification-page.html

Comment: The extension does not, what I want.

Comment: you used default calender controll of magento or any custom?

Comment: The default dob.phtml is included, which just uses the varien controller to check if a date has been entered (this is a DEFAULT phtml, and not a custom one)

Comment: You can apply trick, to not select some specific year here.